# Assigning the value of a column if another column matches a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a need to scrape a large list of links. Once I am done scraping a link, I would read a csv file where this link is present, and update a value signifying that the link has been scraped already (assigned as 1). The issue I am facing is that being new to Pandas, I am not being able to find the proper way to assign a value to the column after finding it.

My dataframe:

```
    Drug    Link    Scraped
0   ADHD (5)    https://example.com/prescriptions/adhd  0
1   Acne (354)  https://example.com/prescriptions/acne  0
2   Alcohol Addiction (12)  https://example.com/prescriptions/alcohol-...   0
... ... ... ...
152 Vomitting/Emesis (312)  https://www.example.com/prescriptions/vomittin...   0
153 rows × 3 columns
```

What I want to do is, check whether the column Link equals a particular value, and if so, change the value at column Scraped to 1

First trying to find the row:

```
df.loc[df['Link'] == 'https://www.example.com/prescriptions/adhd']
Drug    Link    Scraped
0   ADHD (5)    https://www.example.com/prescriptions/adhd  0
```

Trying to read the value at Scraped:

```
df.loc[df['Link'] == 'https://www.example.com/prescriptions/adhd'].at[0, 'Scraped']
0
```

Next, I'm trying to assign a value to Scraped, changing it to 1

```
df.loc[df['Link'] == 'https://www.example.com/prescriptions/adhd'].at[0, 'Scraped']=1
```

Next, trying to reread the value:

```
df.loc[df['Link'] == 'https://www.example.com/prescriptions/adhd'].at[0, 'Scraped']
0
```

So it seems the value hasnt changed at all. Am I doing something wrong here? What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the value without the "at":

```
df.loc[df['Link'] == 'https://www.example.com/prescriptions/adhd', 'Scraped']=1
```